# SQL*Plus spool only data and exclude errors

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, spool

I'm using .Bat file to execute an sql script, similar to this one

```
SET HEAD OFF
SET ECHO OFF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1;

SPOOL D:\oracle\results.TXT

SELECT name FROM employee where employee_number = 123;

SPOOL OFF;
EXIT;
```

if the query runs I'll get the results without a problem, but if the database is down or something cause an oracle Error happens, I'll get an error in the text file ( which I don't want to), my question is:

- Is there a way to spool the data if only the query runs without errors and to exclude if there is an error? or at least if there is an error.
- Can I write a certain text in the results.txt file instead of oracle error?

Comment: If you're using Oracle, tag that product!

Comment: You could do a dummy `select 42 from dual` before the `spool` which would terminate the script if the database wasn't available

Comment: *but if the database is down or something cause an oracle Error happens, I'll get an error in the text file* If the database is down, how would you even connect through SQL*Plus and execute the query? Unless you connect, there is no way spool would be executed.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using oracle 10g